# Georeferencing multispectral data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, georeferencing, landsat

I often have to georeference Landsat data image to map (often raw data without geometric corrections). The way I am doing this is to open up one channel and set my GCPs and save them into a txt file. After that I open each individual channel and am loading the GCPs from the txt file to each image and I am rectifying each channel.

Is there a faster way to do this so that I don't have to load and georeference each channel separately?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Comment: which Landsat? what level? why do you need to georeference the image? read this: http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat_Processing_Details.php and this http://landsat.usgs.gov/processing_level_of_the_Landsat_scene_I_have_downloaded.php

Comment: not all my data is L1gt corrected...I have some Landsat 5 data in the Arctic which doesn't match the rest of my data (I am using a topographical map and also Landsat 8 data as reference data, they seem to be geometrically correct). The Landsat 5 data is L1G processed and has shifts of about 40 km! Thats why I'd like to georeference it manually so that it matches my other scenes.

Comment: stack all layers and then georeference it (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/04/08/stacking-layers-of-imagery-in-arcgis/)